# A kind of pivot table using Symfony2 and Doctrine

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine, data-modeling

I'm developing a KPI management tool for application Quality services with Symfony, Doctrine and jQuery.

I created three entities which are:

- Application (ID, Name, ...)
- KPI (ID, Name, Category, ...)
- Value (Application_ID, KPI_ID, Month, Value)

so my value table has some values like:

```
ID_APP  |     ID_Kpi     |     Month   |     Value

10      |        1       |  January-15 |   40,00

10      |        2       |  January-15 |   50,00

10      |        3       |  January-15 |   true

10      |        4       |  January-15 |   commentaire

22      |        1       |  January-15 |   40,00

22      |        2       |  January-15 |   40,00

etc...
```

But I need to print it like this:

```
Application|   Month   | KPI 1 | KPI 2 | KPI 3   |     KPI 4   |  .......

10         |January-15 |  40   | 50    | true    | commentaire | .....

22         |January-15 |  40   | 40    | false   | commentaire | .....
```

I didn't manage to do it. I don't know if my conception and modeling are good.

I manage to get the format I want (in MySQL) with this query:

```
$sql = "select a.id, a.name, v.date, 
GROUP_CONCAT(if(id_kpi = 400, value, NULL)) AS 'Coverage', 
GROUP_CONCAT(if(id_kpi = 401, value, NULL)) AS 'Automation', 
GROUP_CONCAT(if(id_kpi = 402, value, NULL)) AS 'NEW TC',
GROUP_CONCAT(if(id_kpi = 403, value, NULL)) AS 'TOTAL TC',
GROUP_CONCAT(if(id_kpi = 409, value, NULL)) AS 'Release/Month'

from applications as a
left join piqua_kpi.values as v on a.id = v.id_application
group by a.name, v.date";
```

but I didn't manage to do the same with Doctrine and get an object that I can use.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what kind of guidance you are after here? Are you looking for a SQL or Doctrine query or expression to get the format you desire? If so, can you show what code you have, and what you have tried?

Comment: ^ If you have fixed it, great! Please add that as an answer, not as a comment. Or if you have fixed in SQL and would like it in DQL, please add it to the question. (If you would like it in DQL but only have an SQL attempt, it will be instructive for you to _try_ expressing it the Doctrine way - people familiar with this ORM may see what you are trying to do, and your attempt may prompt more answers).

Comment: I added it to the question, sorry.

Comment: I don't know about doctrine and symfony2, but generally issues of data display are best handled in the presentation layer. So just return a simple, well ordered array, and loop through to generate the data grid.

Comment: But it's not just a matter of display, it's also to implement an "inline editable grid" so as i can permit the user to edit the datas in the grid and make the update easily

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an approach I used to create a series of crosstab reports for a client.  Doing so required abstracting at least some of the formatting of a pivot table. Hope it helps.

First, an example of a report:
[image: Crosstab income report]

In this report, the county entity (linked to the address of a household) is the column, and the household entities income bracket is the row entry.  The cells are counts of households contacted in the given time period with the row and column characteristics.

The controller (there are three pieces):

```
public function incomeProfileAction(Request $request)
{
    $form = $this->createForm(new ReportCriteriaType());
    $criteria = $request->request->get('report_criteria');
    $form->handleRequest($request);
    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $response = new Response();
        $reportData = $this->income($criteria);
        $content = $this->profiler($reportData);
        $response->setContent($content);

        return $response;
    }

    return $this->render('ManaClientBundle:Statistics:report_criteria.html.twig', array(
                'form' => $form->createView(),
                'extra' => 'profile',
                'formPath' => "income_profile",
                'title' => 'Report criteria',
                'criteriaHeader' => 'Select income profile reporting criteria',
    ));
}

private function income($criteria)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $xp = $this->container->get('mana.crosstab');
    $dateCriteria = $xp->setDateCriteria($criteria);
    $columnType = $criteria['columnType'];
    $rowLabels = $em->getRepository('ManaClientBundle:Income')->rowLabels($dateCriteria);
    $colLabels = $em->getRepository('ManaClientBundle:' . $columnType)->colLabels($dateCriteria);
    $data = $em->getRepository('ManaClientBundle:Income')->crossTabData($dateCriteria, $columnType);

    $reportData = [
        'reportTitle' => 'Household Income',
        'reportSubTitle' => 'For the period ',
        'criteria' => $criteria,
        'rowHeader' => 'Income bracket',
        'rowLabels' => $rowLabels,
        'colLabels' => $colLabels,
        'data' => $data,
    ];

    return $reportData;
}

private function profiler($reportData)
{
    $xp = $this->container->get('mana.crosstab');
    $profile = $xp->crosstabQuery($reportData['data'], $reportData['rowLabels'], $reportData['colLabels']);
    $reports = $this->get('reports');
    $specs = $reports->getSpecs($reportData['criteria']);


    return $this->renderView("ManaClientBundle:Statistics:profile.html.twig", ['profile' => $profile,
                'rowHeader' => $reportData['rowHeader'],
                'rowLabels' => $reportData['rowLabels'],
                'colLabels' => $reportData['colLabels'],
                'reportTitle' => $reportData['reportTitle'],
                'reportSubTitle' => $reportData['reportSubTitle'],
                'date' => new \DateTime(),
                'specs' => $specs,
    ]);
}
```

Template:

```
{% set start = specs.startDate|date('F, Y') %}
{% set end = specs.endDate|date('F, Y') %}
<h3 style="text-align: center;">{{ reportTitle }}</h3>
<h4 style="text-align: center;">{{ reportSubTitle }} {{ start }}{% if (start != end) %} through {{ end }}{% endif %}</h4>
<table class="table table-striped table-condensed">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>{{ rowHeader }}
                {%- for colLabel in colLabels -%}
            <th style="text-align: right;">{{ colLabel }} </th>
                {%- endfor -%}
            <th style="text-align: right;">Total</th>
        </tr>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td>Total
                {% for total in profile.total %}
                <td style="text-align: right">{{ total|number_format }}
                {% endfor %}
    <tbody>
        {% for rowLabel in rowLabels -%}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ rowLabel }}
                    {%- for colLabel in colLabels -%}
                <td style="text-align: right">
                    {%- if profile[rowLabel][colLabel] is defined -%}
                    {{ profile[rowLabel][colLabel]|number_format }}{%- else -%}
                    0{%- endif -%}

                {% endfor %}
            <td style="text-align: right">{{ profile[rowLabel]['total']|number_format }}
        </tr>
        {%- endfor -%}
</table>
```

The crosstab service:

```
class Crosstab
{
    private $em;

    public function __construct(EntityManager $em) {
        $this->em = $em;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param array $data = data array
     * @param array $rowLabels
     * @param array $colLabels
     * @return array
     */
    public function crosstabQuery($data, $rowLabels, $colLabels)
    {
        $profile = $this->profileArray( $rowLabels, $colLabels);
        foreach ($data as $array) {
            if (!array_key_exists('total', $profile[$array['rowLabel']])) {
                $profile[$array['rowLabel']]['total'] = 0;
            }
            $profile[$array['rowLabel']][$array['colLabel']] = $array['N'];
            $profile[$array['rowLabel']]['total'] += $array['N'];
        }
        foreach ($profile as $key => $array) {
            if (!array_key_exists('total', $array)) {
                $profile[$key]['total'] = 0;
            }
        }
        $profile['total'] = [];
        foreach ($profile as $row => $array) {
            foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
                if (!array_key_exists($key, $profile['total'])) {
                    $profile['total'][$key] = 0;
                }
                $profile['total'][$key] += $value;
            }
        }

        return $profile; 
    }

    private function profileArray($rows, $cols)
    {
        $colKeys = [];
        foreach ($cols as $col) {
            $colKeys[$col] = 0;
        }
        $profile = [];
        foreach ($rows as $row) {
            $profile[$row] = $colKeys;
        }

        return $profile;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param string $query
     * @param array $criteria ['startMonth', 'startYear', 'endMonth', 'endYear']
     * @return string
     */
    public function setDateCriteria($criteria)
    {
        $startMonth = $criteria['startMonth'];
        $startYear = $criteria['startYear'];
        $startText = $startYear . '-' . $startMonth . '-' . '01';
        $endMonth = $criteria['endMonth'];
        $endYear = $criteria['endYear'];
        $endDate = new \DateTime($endMonth . '/01/' . $endYear);
        $endText = $endDate->format('Y-m-t');

        return "'$startText' AND '$endText' ";

    }
}
```

County repository:

```
class CountyRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    public function colLabels($dateCriteria)
    {
        $str = "select distinct cty.county from county cty
            join contact c on c.county_id = cty.id
            where c.contact_date BETWEEN __DATE_CRITERIA__ 
            order by county";
        $sql = str_replace('__DATE_CRITERIA__', $dateCriteria, $str);
        $conn = $this->getEntityManager()->getConnection();
        $stmt = $conn->executeQuery($sql);
        $colArray = $stmt->fetchAll();
        $colLabels = [];
        foreach ($colArray as $array) {
            $colLabels[] = $array['county'];
        }

        return $colLabels;
    }
```

Income repository:

```
class IncomeRepository extends EntityRepository
{

    public function rowLabels($dateCriteria)
    {
        $str = "select distinct i.income 
            from income i
            join household h on h.income_id = i.id
            join contact c on c.household_id = h.id 
            WHERE c.contact_date BETWEEN __DATE_CRITERIA__
            AND i.enabled = TRUE order by i.id ";
        $sql = str_replace('__DATE_CRITERIA__', $dateCriteria, $str);
        $conn = $this->getEntityManager()->getConnection();
        $stmt = $conn->executeQuery($sql);
        $rowArray = $stmt->fetchAll();
        $rowLabels = [];
        foreach ($rowArray as $array) {
            $rowLabels[] = $array['income'];
        }

        return $rowLabels;
    }

    public function crossTabData($dateCriteria, $profileType)
    {
        $str = "SELECT r.__TYPE__ colLabel, i.income rowLabel, COUNT(DISTINCT h.id) N " .
                "FROM household h " .
                "JOIN contact c ON c.household_id = h.id " .
                "LEFT JOIN __TYPE__ r ON r.id = c.__TYPE___id " .
                "LEFT JOIN income i ON h.income_id = i.id " .
                "WHERE c.contact_date BETWEEN __DATE_CRITERIA__ " .
                "AND i.enabled = TRUE " .
                "GROUP BY colLabel, rowLabel";
        $sql1 = str_replace('__DATE_CRITERIA__', $dateCriteria, $str);
        $sql = str_replace('__TYPE__', $profileType, $sql1);
        $conn = $this->getEntityManager()->getConnection();
        $stmt = $conn->executeQuery($sql);

        return $stmt->fetchAll();
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer, i'll check that now :)

Comment: Another option is [PivotTable.js](http://nicolas.kruchten.com/pivottable/examples/).  It's very clever.  I didn't use it because it was not appropriate for my client.

Answer (score 0):

Your example helped me a lot. Thank you.
So, I used the :

```
$conn = $this->getEntityManager()->getConnection();
$stmt = $conn->executeQuery($sql);
$rowArray = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

in my repository to get my data with this query which return the result as i want:

```
$sql = "select a.id, a.name, v.date, 
GROUP_CONCAT(if(id_kpi = 400, value, NULL)) AS 'Coverage', 
GROUP_CONCAT(if(id_kpi = 401, value, NULL)) AS 'Automation', 
GROUP_CONCAT(if(id_kpi = 402, value, NULL)) AS 'NEW TC',
GROUP_CONCAT(if(id_kpi = 403, value, NULL)) AS 'TOTAL TC'
from applications as a
left join piqua_kpi.values as v on a.id = v.id_application
".$filter.$date." 
group by a.name, v.date";
```

and then in my view, I loop with twig through my array to print my values.

So now, i'll try to add an inline editable grid to edit this figures and add new values.. I hope this way of getting my data will not make the things harder..